# Unity firestore - How to run GetSnapshotAsync() right after CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync()?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

using Unity, I am trying to intialize my the firestore using CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync() and getting a document from firestore using GetSnapshotAsync(). From a [firebase article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html), it is possible to add a continuation for the task with ContinueWithOnMainThread as shown in the example here:

```
Debug.Log("Checking Dependencies");
FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(fixTask =>
{
    Assert.IsNull(fixTask.Exception);
    Debug.Log("Authenticating");
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(authTask =>
    {
        Assert.IsNull(authTask.Exception);
        Debug.Log("Signed in!");
        var successes = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Successes", 0);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Successes", ++successes);
        Debug.Log($"Successes: {successes}");
        auth.SignOut();
        Debug.Log("Signed Out");
    });
});
```

However, this is not the case for my project, where I want to use GetSnapshotAsync() instead to retrieve some 'level' data - everything inside the block is not running.

```
 private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Database awake ");
        //check if all dependency is in project
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            string lvCode = "oHFxRAIpIHfT8moiYSl9";
            Debug.Log("Get level :" + lvCode);

            DocumentReference levelref = db.Collection("level").Document(lvCode);

            levelref.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(querySnapshotTask =>
            {
                //Debug.Log here is not ran
                Debug.Log("Completed? " + querySnapshotTask.Result);
                Debug.Log("Faulted? " + querySnapshotTask.IsFaulted);

            });
        });
}
```

Can someone explain why is this happening to my code and possibly provide some alternatives that use the ContinueWith methods? (as opposed to await and coroutine solutions)

Comment: Have you tried also using `ContinueWithOnMainThread` for the first `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` task? Not sure how it is implemented but maybe it assumes the thread where it was started as the "main" thread?

Answer (score 2):

Author of that article here

I can't quite see if you're doing anything wrong, but my guess is that maybe you're doing a `db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance` outside of that block (ignore this if you're doing a lazy iniitalization). Calling that before `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` could be causing your issue (`CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync` verifies that `DefaultInstance` can be called without erroring out).

Subbing out your `db` reference might fix it:

```
private void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Database awake ");
    //check if all dependency is in project
    FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        string lvCode = "oHFxRAIpIHfT8moiYSl9";
        Debug.Log("Get level :" + lvCode);

        DocumentReference levelref = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance.Collection("level").Document(lvCode);

        levelref.GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(querySnapshotTask =>
        {
            //Debug.Log here is not ran
            Debug.Log("Completed? " + querySnapshotTask.Result);
            Debug.Log("Faulted? " + querySnapshotTask.IsFaulted);

        });
    });
}
```

Also, pay close attention to any error logging, changing the first `ContinueWith` to `ContinueWithOnMainThread` *might* reveal more errors (some versions of Unity do fail to report errors in background tasks).

Finally it's worth checking that you actually do have Firestore setup with your current game. Assuming you have a `google-services.json` or `GoogleService-Info.plist` in your `Assets/` directory, you can go to "Window>Firebase>Documentation":
[image: Menu open to "Window>Firebase>Documentation"]

And click "Open in Console" to jump right to your project and double check that Firestore is setup:
[image: "Documentation" page open with "Open in Console" visible]

If you do find that changing the first `ContinueWith` to `ContinueWithOnMainThread` fixes your issue completely, it could be worth [filing a bug](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues). Generally the Firebase libraries should be thread safe, and since Firestore is in beta maybe it's a use case that was missed.